# Dynamic ItemDisplayBinding for Picker

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The Picker has ItemDisplayBinding property to set Itemsource's property name to display by using this `"{Binding PropertyA}"` syntax.
But I have UI conditions that relating with changing property name to display dynamically.
I have a property like this.

```cs
public string GetPropertyToDisplay 
{
    If (ID == 1)
    {
        return "PropertyA";
    }
    else if (ID == 2)
    {
        return "PropertyB";
    }
}
```

What should I do If I want this property to be binding instead `"{Binding PropertyA}"` ?

Comment: why don't you create a "Display" read-only property that returns either PropertyA or PropertyB as appropriate?

Comment: I haven't knowledge about "Display", Thanks for giving a suggestion. @Jason

Answer (score 2):

Use the converter to figure it out.
Firstly, create your own converter:

```cs
public class PikcerDisplayConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Model model = value as Model;
        if(ID == 1)
        {
            return model.PropertyA;
        }           
        return model.PropertyB;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then consume this converter in your xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:PikcerDisplayConverter x:Key="PikcerDisplayConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource PikcerDisplayConverter}}"/>
```

At last, each picker's item will go into this converter before displaying. So you could choose what you want to show there.

Comment: goog copy/paste from xamarin forum;
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/153715/dynamic-itemdisplaybinding-for-picker

Answer (score 1):

**If ID is belong to one of ItemDisplayBinding's property**.Refer as bellow.

Create a `PropertyDisplay` property in it, this can be used to display whethre is PropertyA or PropertyB ,either other Property.

**Property class** : Contain PropertyA ,PropertyB ,etc.

```
public class Property 
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string PropertyA { set; get; }
    public string PropertyB { set; get; }

    private string propertyDisplay = "Property";

    public string PropertyDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            if (ID == 1)
            {
                return PropertyA;
            }
            else if (ID == 2)
            {
                return PropertyB;
            }else
            return propertyDisplay;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel class** : ItemSource ,set test data as follow:

```
public List<Property> listProperty { set; get; }

public ViewModel()
{

    listProperty = new List<Property>();

    listProperty.Add(new Property
    {
        ID = 1,
        Name = "Alex1",
        PropertyA = "10",
        PropertyB = "Ejemplo"
    });
    listProperty.Add(new Property
    {
        ID = 2,
        Name = "Alex2",
        PropertyA = "20",
        PropertyB = "Ejemplo"
    });

}
```

**Xaml** : Picker

```
<Picker Title="select" TextColor="Aqua" ItemsSource="{Binding listProperty}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding PropertyDisplay}"/>
```

**Final effects**:

[image]